Allowing for duplicates when copying images to folders in Rstudio
So im trying to copy spesific files from different directories into one folder by using the command :
for (file in file_paths) {
  file.copy(file, destination, overwrite = TRUE)
}


Here the file paths is a chr list containing local placement of files
destination is my folder where i want it to go.
However, the image paths consists of a directory name. Some of these images have the same name base on timestamps.
[1] "E:/Masterdirectory/2023/RENAMED/CAD12_RENAMED/101RECNX/101RECNX__2023-05-12__17-05-00(1).JPG"
[2] "E:/Masterdirectory/2023/RENAMED/CAD15_RENAMED/100RECNX/100RECNX__2023-04-23__10-10-00(1).JPG"
[3] "E:/Masterdirectory/2023/RENAMED/CAD16_RENAMED/100RECNX/100RECNX__2023-04-23__10-10-00(1).JPG"
[4] "E:/Masterdirectory/2023/RENAMED/CAD17_RENAMED/101RECNX/101RECNX__2023-05-12__17-05-00(1).JPG"

However, when i use the copy function only two images remain after copying, and i need all 4 to be in the same folder, without changing the names of images - as they provide key information.
different approaches with different AIs but i cant remane the images
